# Best way to open an internal project to world as a Saas

Tags: laravel, database-design

We have developed an internal crm and used it for the last months. Now we have decided to open it to the public as a Saas project and I'm wondering which is the best solution to upgrade the database structure that actually is made for only one company and expand it to be able to manage multiple paying customers.

At the moment the scheduled solution is to add a "customer" field to every column in the database and upgrade the backend logic to use this field.

Are there more elegant solutions to this problem?
The database is mySql and the backend is made with laravel.

Comment: there are many ways, you can just setup multiple instance of your crm for each user. alternatively, you have to do a major overhaul on the database and the software as you have said in your question. this kind of question will draw opinions a lot, so its kinda bad.

Answer (score 0):

CRM Data can be very sensitive and you need to be extremely careful not to "leak" data to wrong customers.

For an existing app, I would argue for a system to create fresh DB for each customer.

You would have 1 codebase that connects to customer specific DB.
This way you dont need to change too much in your current DB structure, but "just" implement the mechanism to use the correct DB according to customer account.

This is how I would do it :
[image]

In any wah this is a massive paradigm change from an internal app to a SAAS platform app, and you should identify the necessary steps to go through to achieve the desired result.